# How the cdc retention value can be changed for the cleanup job?

Tags: sql-server, database, logging, change-data-capture

I'm implementing a logging feature on a asp.net mvc2 application, that uses SqlServer2008 as a database and Entity Framework as a data model.

I enabled CDC feature of SqlServer and it's logging changes well, but I just noticed that some of the old logging data is erased.

Does anyone know what's default period CDC keeps records, and does anyone know how could I set it to indefinite value.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I just discovered that the default retention value is 4320 minutes = 72 hours = 3 days.

It should be configurable by using

```
sp_cdc_change_job @job_type='cleanup', @retention=minutes
```

> The maximum value is 52494800 (100 years). If specified, the value must be a positive integer. Retention is valid only for cleanup jobs.

Here's the [link to the more detail explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510748.aspx) of sp_cdc_change_job procedure

Hope this will help someone else, too :D.

Comment: How can you read the existing value?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to retain the CDC data indefinitly, you can simply [disable the CDC cleanup job](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a073ef0-9a49-488f-a6c5-7b4b1c71f4c0/automatic-cleanup-for-change-data-capture?forum=sqldatabaseengine):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your database server
2. In the object explorer, expand “<instance> | SQL Server Agent | Jobs”
3. Find the job for cleanup named “cdc.<database name>_cleanup”.
4. Right-click the job and select "disable"

Here is a sample picture of where to find the option:

[image: How to disable CDC Cleanup]

After you disabled the cleanup job, the CDC data will no longer get removed after a certain time interval.

Comment: What's the difference between Stop Job and Disable in this case?

Comment: My guess: stop halts it until the next Server restart, disable halts it permanently.

Comment: Thanks Atticae for the answer. Have a query on CDC...can we enable CDC for a particular DML operation - only for update?

Comment: @Mark13426 - "Stop Job" stops a job that is currently running. It will remain enabled, and run again at its next scheduled time. "Disable" will prevent the job form running at its next scheduled time. If a currently running job is disabled, the current run will continue (unless you also use "Stop Job" on it, of course :-) ).

Answer (score 8):

By default it deletes anything older than 3 days, to change the default value to 14 days  use the following script

```
use <Your database>
go

SELECT ([retention])/((60*24)) AS Default_Retention_days ,*
FROM msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs
go

EXEC <Your database>.sys.sp_cdc_change_job 
@job_type=N'Cleanup'
,@retention=20160 -- <60 min *24 hrs * 14 days >
go

SELECT ([retention])/((60*24)) AS Default_Retention_days ,*
FROM msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs
Go
```